# While loop in MIPS (Beginner in MIPS)

Tags: loops, assembly, while-loop, label, mips

I am trying to write a program to calculate nCr where n and r are input by the user.
My approach is following:

1. I ask to user to enter value of n.
2. Then I ask the user to enter value of r.
3. Then I calculate value of n-r.
4. Then using three while loops I calculate the value of n! r! and (n-r)!
5. Then I divide by n! by r! and (n-r)!
6. Then I display it to the user.
7. Following is my code:

   ```
   .data 
        prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the value of n:\n"
        prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the value of r:\n"
        message: .asciiz "The value of nCr is: "

    .text
         #Prompt the user to enter value of n
         li $v0,4
         la $a0,prompt1
         syscall

         #Get the value of n
         li $v0,5
         syscall

         #Store the value of n in $t0
         move $t0,$v0

         #Prompt the user to enter value of r
         li $v0,4
         la $a0,prompt1
         syscall

         #Get the value of r
         li $v0,5
         syscall

         #Store the value of r in $t2


         move $t2,$v0

         #Getting the value of (n-r)
         sub $t4,$t0,$t2

         #Calculating value of n!
         addi $t1,$zero,1

         while:
               blt $t0,1,exit
               mul $t1,$t1,$t0
               sub $t0,$t0,1
               j while
         exit:
               li $v0,10
               syscall

        #Calculating the value of r!
        addi $t3,$zero,1

        while:
              blt $t2,1,exit
              mul $t3,$t3,$t2
              sub $t2,$t2,1
              j while

         exit:
              li $v0,10
              syscall

        #Calculating the value of (n-r)!
        addi $t5,$zero,1

        while:
              blt $t4,1,exit
              mul $t5,$t5,$t4
              sub $t4,$t4,1
              j while

       exit:
             li $v0,10
             syscall

       #Getting the final value
       div $s0,$t1,$t3
       div $s1,$s0,$t5

       #Displaying the message
       li $v0,4
       la $a0,message
       syscall

       #Display the answer
       addi $a0,$s1,0
       syscall
   ```

The Error which I am getting is this:

1. line 46 column 6: label "while" already defined.
2. line 46 column 6: label "exit" already defined.

What I am doing wrong here? Is it not the correct way to use three while loops in a mips

Comment: You can't have three global symbols with the same name. How is the assembler going to know which one you're referring to? Aside from that, once you leave the first loop, you're executing system call 10 which will terminate the program. Nothing else in your program will be executed after that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Program is working now:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write `while:` in your program, you are creating a label named `while`, which is an alias for the line number where you place it. Within one file, you can only create one label with a certain name.

A solution for your problem would be to name the labels `while1`, `while2` and `while3`. Same holds for your `exit` labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working now:)

Comment: Another strategy is to try to come up with meaningful names for your labels, like `n_fac:` or `r_loop:`, instead of just a mess of numbers.  @anurag1905: Also note that `x! / y!` is `prod(i=y..x)`; instead of calculating two huge numbers and then dividing them, just skip the multiplies that cancel out.

Comment: Great Suggestion. I will keep them in mind. Thankyou:)